# Which programming languages support type inference from variable names?

Tags: compiler, type

Which programming languages support type inference from variable names?

By 'type inference', I mean, for example, in Swift, how if you `let x = 39` then the compiler knows `x` is an `Integer`, because `39` is an integer.

Now, it's conventional in Swift to use the keyword `is` at the beginning of `Boolean` variables. For example `let isCool = true`. However if we do `let isCool = 0`, the compiler will infer the type of `isCool` to be `Integer` instead of `Bool`, even though any human programmer would know it was supposed to be a `Bool` due to the presence of `is` at the beginning of the variable name.

So, it occurred to me, I wonder if there are any programming languages where you can give the compiler a clue to help it infer the type by using keywords in the variable name itself? Has anyone ever seen something like that?

Side note:

This was not intended to be a question about the merits of doing this, but just so you know, the reason I asked it was because I thought it is something that could be a feature that might allow for cleaner code in webservice integration layers, due to the necessity of parsing a lot of JSON into variables and languages like Swift making this a pain with all their enforced type safety.

So here is an example of how this might improve some code in Swift.

Suppose customersJSON is some data that came from a webservice response. If the server has a bug then the contents might not be the types we expect. So a strictly type safe language like Swift 3 currently enforces code that looks like the following:

```
    let customersJSON = "[{\"customerName\":\"Alice\",\"customerAge\":42},{\"customerName\":808,\"customerAge\":88}]".data(using: .utf8)!
    var customersArray: [Any]!
    do {
        customersArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: customersJSON, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions()) as? Array
    } 
    catch {
        print(error)
        return;
    }
    for customer in customersArray {
        guard let customerDict = customer as? [String:Any],
            let customerName = customerDict["customerName"] as? String,
            let customerAge = customerDict["customerAge"] as? Int 
            else {break}
        print("customerName: \(customerName), customerAge: \(customerAge)") 
    }
```

Note that when we assign `dict["customerName"]` to `customerName`, we have to tell the compiler that `customerName` should be a `String` with the syntax `as? String`.

Of course, human beings know that names are always strings; as a programmer it's just annoying to me to always have to tell the compiler this, if for example, I have several different things like `productName` and `itemName` and `discountName` etc. that must be handled in various response handlers. I'd much rather tell the compiler one single time that any variable whose name ends in "Name" is a String.

I'd much rather set a global preference in my app, using regex matching patterns to give the compiler a heads up, like:

```
Infer ".*Array":[Any]!
Infer ".*Name":String
Infer ".*Age":Int
Infer ".*Dict":[String:Any]
```

Then we can do:

```
    let customersJSON = "[{\"customerName\":\"Alice\",\"customerAge\":42},{\"customerName\":808,\"customerAge\":88}]".data(using: .utf8)!

    var customersArray
    do {
        customersArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: customersJSON, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions())
    } 
    catch {
        print(error)
        return;
    }
    for customer in customersArray {
        guard let customerDict = customer,
            let customerName = customerDict["customerName"],
            let customerAge = customerDict["customerAge"] 
            else {break}
        print("customerName: \(customerName), customerAge: \(customerAge)") 
    }
```

... and still have total type safety of Swift, without all the ugliness. Now it looks more like a dynamically typed language's code. I'm not saying it's "better" this way, but I do think it makes for more elegant, more readable code. YMMV

Comment: In the original versions of Fortran, the type of a variable is solely determined by the first character of its name. There are no type declarations. This is not type inference, though.

Comment: Can you explain how naming a variable `intNumber` would be superior to `int number`?

Comment: *if we do let isCool = 0, the compiler will infer the type of isCool to be Integer instead of Bool, even though any human programmer would know it was supposed to be a Bool*  Not really, this human programmer (honest, I'm not a robot) would think it was a poorly named variable of integer type.

Comment: @Robert Harvey  Any variable would carry the type information awareness into implementation code. You would never have to refer to the declaration part to know the type of a variable. We could probably come up with some reasons not to do it, it isn't that pure from a CS perspective, it is a form of "in-band signaling". But there is some convenience to it.

Comment: Some Basic dialects require a `$` in the end of string variable names.

Comment: It's unclear whether you're asking about the merits of the idea or for a list of languages that contain it.

Comment: Also, forgetting the type system, `bool isCool = 0` is bad and you should feel bad. I prefer when languages prevent this sort of thing.

Comment: I think you are better off looking for a linter/SA tool to enofrce this as a style rule

Comment: @JörgWMittag IIRC, it was only default types in FORTRAN, thus the joke "GOD is real, unless declared integer" (variables starting with i, j, k, l (and possibly m and n) were considered integers, all others real, and by "real" I actually mean floating-point).

Comment: @Vatine, FORTRAN took I, J, K, L, M, and N initial letters to denote integers.  This came straight from common usage in mathematics, where those letters were commonly used as summation and multiplication indices.

Comment: I have edited the question to clarify what it is about (just the existing languages, not the merits of it).

Comment: Just to add to the list... VB6 had what were called "Type Hints". `Dim $foo` was a string. Can't recall the rest of them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Very early versions of FORTRAN used the first letter of the variable name to denote the type, for basic types INTEGER and REAL.  Double precision (extended-precision reals) had to be declared explicitly.

As of at least FORTRAN IV, at least some versions of FORTRAN allowed explicit declarations to override the first-letter rule.

FORTRAN 77 allowed one to specify one's own personal first-letter rules, and to disable them altogether.  (Example: IMPLICIT INTEGER(NONE))

It should be mentioned that it was generally accepted in the computing community by at least the mid-1960s that default type rules and implicit variable declarations were a very bad idea.  Tony Hoare reports having his ears soundly boxed by the ALGOL Committee when he proposed such modification to ALGOL.  (He mentioned that this was before the probably-apocryphal story of the lost Venus probe, due to a typographical error that nevertheless yielded a syntactically-legal FORTRAN program, became widely known.)

Answer (score 7):

> I've never seen anything like that, but wouldn't it be a cool feature
>   to be able to set up some keywords to mean certain things, so that you
>   could avoid repetitive boilerplate and have more readable code, to
>   boot?

Sorry, no.  **This is not a good idea.**

**Variable declaration is a meaningful step, not "boilerplate".**

A feature of good language design is that variable declarations must be explicit.  Being able to use variables that have not been declared can make a minor typo into a significant bug, and also there can be quite problematic hidden problems caused by collisions in variable names between different scopes.

While there are some languages that allow variables without declaring them (Perl, Javascript, etc.), this is discouraged, except for in quick hacks/scripts, and usually language features have been added later to turn off this behavior.

So, that means that even in your theoretical language, good practice would still require a declaration line for any significant development.  Something like this:

```
var intNum;
```

Does not save code compared to this:

```
int num;
```

**It harms rather than aiding readability.**

Reasons why it is not needed:

- **A variable's type is most often clear from the context.**
- **Well-designed code will have plenty of hints about variable type.**

  - Good practice is to break code into small functions, which (in most languages) have a prototype indicating the type of the arguments.
  - Variables should be declared as close to their point of use as possible, and globals should be avoided.  This is important for other reasons, and means a variable declaration is often quite closeto the code you are working on.
- **Type information is also easily available in development tools.**

Reasons why it may cause more harm than good:

- **It adds noise to the code.** If you have a variable `x` that is used 10 times, being forced to name it `intx` instead adds a lot of extra unnecessary stuff to the code.  And all variables of the same type now look kind of similar, making it hard to distinguish them from each other.
- **It really breaks down on more complex types.**  This scheme would be workable if you only had a few basic types like int, float, etc.  But in modern languages (well, actually even in old languages like C), you can have user-defined types that are much more complex.  How well does this idea work with object oriented programming, where the type of an object might be `DoohickyFrobulatorFactory`?
- **It also doesn't help with pointers/references.**  A pointer may be used to refer to objects of multiple types.  While you could call it `ptrFoo`, arguably this isn't really all that helpful information.  What is more meaningful is what sort of object it is pointing to.  But the system doesn't help with that.
- **It makes it harder to change the type.** What if you decide your `int` should be a `long int`, or similar?   This should be a trivial change, but it's more complex if you have to rename the variable.

Of course, you already could use this naming convention if you wanted to (just not enforced by the compiler).  It's actually an established naming convention called [Hungarian Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation), and it was fairly popular at one point.  But it is widely discouraged today.  See the linked article for more information.

Comment: It does save code, the point is you would not have to declare the variable at all because its type would be implicitly known from its name. The cases you make seem mostly emotional ("you can't do that!"), solely based on where you are coming from. It is quite natural, if I step in to tell you something I would not list the words I am going to use upfront either. You would still have properties on a class that provide information about the encapsulated data.

Comment: @MartinMaat the first point in my answer is that "not hav[ing] to declare a variable at all" is poor practice.  I provide multiple specific reasons in my answer, I'm not sure why it's "mostly emotional".

Comment: I find it not so easy to advise against it for any new language. Like the total lack of type-safe in some interpreted languages we all hate so much can have benefits, I can see some merit in this approach too.

Comment: @MartinMaat, I don't hate languages with flexible types.  They are quite useful for many tasks.  In general I oppose blanket statements "never do X because it is bad practice". Goto, global variables, and many other "bad" things can have their uses.  (Even being able to use variables without declaring them is useful for quick scripting--updated my answer because it was too categorical on this point).  But I just don't see any real benefit of this proposed feature, while there are significant downsides.  If you see benefit, I suggest posting an answer.  That would be a nice conribution.

Comment: Your critique suggests that you view my question as an either/or proposition. However, in the part of my question you quoted, I did not say suggest that it would be *always* be better to have the compiler infer type from variable names, nor that this would necessarily be superior to using type declarations or inference in most situations. In fact I agree that in most situations, your objections are quite valid. However you can't seriously believe there are *no situations* in which it would be desirable for a variable name to contain a discrete type symbol.

Comment: @CommaToast your question was about making this a language feature, and I assumed that meant this would be the standard way of declaring variables within the language.  There may be an occasional use case, but I don't think it is a broadly useful feature.

Comment: @MartinMaat: There are two problems.  The first is that implicit variable declarations make it much easier for typographical errors to yield syntactically-correct programs.  Consider "intNum" vs. "intNmu".  Did the programmer intend one variable or two?  Second, how much impact do you want if you have to change the type of a variable?  Consider "charNum" vs. "intNum".  How many places do you have to change the name, as opposed to changing ONE declaration?  Consider "char Num;" vs "int Num;".

Comment: @John I acknowlege the typo issues. Renaming is not an issue with today's refactoring functions in IDEs.

Comment: @MartinMaat, it is not clear that you fully grasp the typo issues.  The Venus probe typo did actually occur.  The resulting program was syntactically correct FORTRAN, but it changed a DO-loop into an assignment to a dead variable.  What is not known, now, is whether it actually caused the total loss of a multi-million dollar spacecraft, or whether it was caught in code review, which prevented the total loss of a multi-million dollar spacecraft.  The ALGOL committee was absolutely correct when it boxed Hoare's ears and blowtorched his backside.

Comment: @CommaToast "you can't seriously believe" -> sure can. If you need the type to be carried with the name something is *badly* wrong with your code. Either you're using the variable too far away from its declaration or it's not being used generically enough. In good code, the concrete type of a variable is essentially unimportant; only the interface matters. Also in good code, you shouldn't have to keep looking up what that interface actually contains. Needing to get this information from the variable name means your code *must* be poorly-designed, in addition to the maintainability nightmare.

Comment: Thirdly, I also never said that the type inferred by the compiler from the variable name should prohibit the concrete type from being, say, a subclass of that inferred type. Because you're right, only the interface matters. What I'm suggesting is not contradictory to that. Fourthly, I never said that you should have to keep looking up what an interface contains. Fifthly, you should never assume that you are the authority on good design, especially of code you've never seen; it's a sign that you probably aren't.... Anyway take a look at the example I listed above. It's a trade-off, I'm sure.

Answer (score 1):

Fortran has already been covered so I will say no more about it….

I don’t know of any programming language that inference a type based on variable or parameter name.    However there are lots of coding standards that recommend how variables, methods, classes etc should be named.

You can then use a coding **style checker** to confirm if the naming standards has been kept to, hence getting an warning (or error) from your build system if use have.

```
let isCool = 0
```